# JTable - prevent the user from de-selecting all elements in the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table with fixed content that I know will never be empty.

I would like to use it as a radio button (loosely speaking): I want always one and only one row selected at a time.

I know already that I can set the selection model to `SINGLE_SELECTION` but (rather unexpectedly) this seems not to prevent the user from deselecting all rows in the table.

Is there a simple way to prevent the user from deselecting all rows in the table?

I can only think of something like:

```
@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {
    if (!listSelectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting() && table.getSelectedRow() == -1) {
        table.selectRow(0);
    }
}
```

but, frankly, it seems a bit too clumsy for such a simple task (and I need to remember the old selection to better implement the pattern)...

Is there a easier/more elegant way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the 'changeSelection' method, to NOT deselect, if this is the last row being deselected, like this

```
public void changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend)
            {
                if(!(toggle && jt.getSelectedRowCount() == 1))
                {
                    super.changeSelection(rowIndex, columnIndex, toggle, extend);
                }
            }
```